# File descriptors: Redirect both input and output to both shell and logfile

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, io-redirection

Below is a solution I found from:
[Create a pipe that writes to multiple files (tee)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288939/create-a-pipe-that-writes-to-multiple-files-tee)

Hence the code below redirects stdout and stderr to the logfile whilst displaying them in the terminal as well.  I was wondering if there is anyway to redirect the stdin to both the terminal and logfile as well.

```
#!/bin/bash 
LOG=./file.log 
PIPE=./logPipe
mkfifo ${PIPE}
exec 3>&1 4>&2
tee -a ${LOG} <${PIPE} >&3 &
exec 1>${PIPE} &
exec 2>&1

printf "%s\n" " Enter Something "
read something

printf "%s\n" " Enter Something "
read something2
printf "\n"

printf "%s\n" " Enter Something "
read something3

mkdir ./test
mkdir ./test
mkdir ./test here

printf "$something $something2 $something3" >> something.out
```

Comment: The terminal is not a shell.  You cannot 'display' something in the shell, but the shell can write data to a terminal to be displayed.

Comment: @William; updated using the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the script command

```
script -c infile.sh
```

```
-c, --command command
  Run the command rather than an interactive shell. This makes it easy for a
  script to capture the output of a program that behaves differently when its
  stdout is not a tty.
```

[saving terminal session](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1404695)

[explainshell.com - script -c](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=script+-c)